# How to trigger annotation @SystemSetup in Hybris?

Tags: java, annotations, sap-commerce-cloud

There is a method annotated with **@SystemSetup** as below, but how to trigger this method?

```
@SystemSetup(extension = IwacockpitsConstants.EXTENSIONNAME)
public class IwaCockpitsSystemSetup{
    @SystemSetup(type = SystemSetup.Type.ALL, process = SystemSetup.Process.ALL)
    public void createCsCockpitUsers(){}
}
```

Also, there is a official comment:

```
/**
 * This class is called during IwaCockpits system setup, either selecting essential or project data.
 * 
 * The main method of this class ({@link #createCsCockpitUsers()} is responsible for creating all the IWA CSCockpit
 * custom groups and their restrictions.
 */
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually Hybris will take care of triggering the method for you in both `update` or `init` process (because `process = Process.ALL`) and while the creation of `essential` or `project` data (because `type = Type.ALL`) this could be done from `HAC` or using `Ant` :

For example try **Update** process with create **Essential** data checked from **HAC** to invoke the method :

[image]

Here are the different cases when the method should be executed depending on `@SystemSetup` inputs.

```java
@SystemSetup(extension = IwacockpitsConstants.EXTENSIONNAME)
public class IwaCockpitsSystemSetup{

    @SystemSetup(process = SystemSetup.Process.INIT, type = SystemSetup.Type.ESSENTIAL)
    public void method_1(){

        //will be executed during the initialization process when the essential data for extension iwacockpits is created.

    }

    @SystemSetup(process = SystemSetup.Process.INIT, type = SystemSetup.Type.PROJECT)
    public void method_2(){

        //will be executed during the initialization process while creation of project data for extension iwacockpits.

    }

    @SystemSetup(process = SystemSetup.Process.UPDATE, type = SystemSetup.Type.ESSENTIAL)
    public void method_3(){

        //will be executed during the update process when the essential data for extension iwacockpits is created.

    }

    @SystemSetup(process = SystemSetup.Process.UPDATE, type = SystemSetup.Type.PROJECT)
    public void method_4){

        //will be executed during the initialization process when the project data for extension iwacockpits is created.

    }

    @SystemSetup(process = SystemSetup.Process.ALL, type = SystemSetup.Type.ALL)
    public void method_5){

        //will be executed during creation of project data or essential data in the same extension, in both init and update.

    }

}
```

Comment: Your answer is very detailed, I've accepted it, thank you! Could you help me solve another problem? [Hybris error occurred while starting server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42470529/hybris-error-occurred-while-starting-server)