# Hybris error occurred while starting server

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

There are some errors occurred while hybris starting. I doubt that it is cased by interruption of my previous updating. I checked **hac->platform->update->create essential data**, I terminated the server when it is updating, then I restarted the server, errors occurred.

```
Unknown error notifying listener de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.solr.impl.DefaultSolrCoresService$1@334b5c28 on tenant master startup : Error creating bean with name 'defaultInterceptorRegistry' defined in class path resource [interceptor-spring.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'interceptorMappings': : Error creating bean with name 'navigationNodePrepareInterceptorMapping' defined in class path resource [cms2-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'navigationNodePrepareInterceptor' while setting bean property 'interceptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'navigationNodePrepareInterceptor' defined in class path resource [cms2-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cmsNavigationService' while setting bean property 'cmsNavigationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultCMSNavigationService' defined in class path resource [cms2-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cmsPageService' while setting bean property 'cmsPageService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'iwaCMSPageService' defined in class path resource [iwacore-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cmsRestrictionService' while setting bean property 'cmsRestrictionService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rankingCMSRestrictionService' defined in class path resource [acceleratorcms-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cmsRestrictionEvaluatorRegistry' while setting bean property 'evaluatorRegistry'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cmsRestrictionEvaluatorRegistry' defined in class path resource [cms2-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'btgSegmentRestrictionEvaluatorMapping' defined in class path resource [btg-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'btgSegmentRestrictionEvaluator' while setting bean property 'restrictionEvaluator'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'btgSegmentRestrictionEvaluator' defined in class path resource [btg-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'btgResultService' while setting bean property 'btgResultService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultBTGResultService' defined in class path resource [btg-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'segmentEvaluatorRegistry' while setting bean property 'segmentEvaluatorRegistry'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultSegmentEvaluatorRegistry' defined in class path resource [btg-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'segmentEvaluator' while setting bean property 'segmentEvaluators' with key [TypedStringValue: value [OPTIMIZED], target type [null]]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultSegmentEvaluator' defined in class path resource [btg-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'actionService' while setting bean property 'actionService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultActionService' defined in class path resource [servicelayer-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'actionExecutionStrategyRegistry' while setting bean property 'executionStrategyRegistry'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'actionExecutionStrategyRegistry': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.action.impl.DefaultActionExecutionStrategyRegistry.setStrategies(java.util.Collection); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processActionExecutionStrategy' defined in class path resource [processengine-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'businessProcessService' while setting bean property 'processService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultBusinessProcessService' defined in class path resource [processengine-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'processDefinitionFactory' while setting bean property 'processDefinitionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultProcessDefinitionFactory' defined in class path resource [processengine-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'iwaConsignmentOrderExceptionEmailAction' is defined; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'navigationNodePrepareInterceptorMapping' defined in class path resource [cms2-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'navigationNodePrepareInterceptor' while setting bean property 'interceptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'navigationNodePrepareInterceptor' defined in class path resource [cms2-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cmsNavigationService' while setting bean property 'cmsNavigationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultCMSNavigationService' defined in class path resource [cms2-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cmsPageService' while setting bean property 'cmsPageService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'iwaCMSPageService' defined in class path resource [iwacore-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cmsRestrictionService' while setting bean property 'cmsRestrictionService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rankingCMSRestrictionService' defined in class path resource [acceleratorcms-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cmsRestrictionEvaluatorRegistry' while setting bean property 'evaluatorRegistry'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cmsRestrictionEvaluatorRegistry' defined in class path resource [cms2-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'btgSegmentRestrictionEvaluatorMapping' defined in class path resource [btg-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'btgSegmentRestrictionEvaluator' while setting bean property 'restrictionEvaluator'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'btgSegmentRestrictionEvaluator' defined in class path resource [btg-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'btgResultService' while setting bean property 'btgResultService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultBTGResultService' defined in class path resource [btg-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'segmentEvaluatorRegistry' while setting bean property 'segmentEvaluatorRegistry'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultSegmentEvaluatorRegistry' defined in class path resource [btg-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'segmentEvaluator' while setting bean property 'segmentEvaluators' with key [TypedStringValue: value [OPTIMIZED], target type [null]]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultSegmentEvaluator' defined in class path resource [btg-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'actionService' while setting bean property 'actionService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultActionService' defined in class path resource [servicelayer-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'actionExecutionStrategyRegistry' while setting bean property 'executionStrategyRegistry'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'actionExecutionStrategyRegistry': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.action.impl.DefaultActionExecutionStrategyRegistry.setStrategies(java.util.Collection); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processActionExecutionStrategy' defined in class path resource [processengine-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'businessProcessService' while setting bean property 'processService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultBusinessProcessService' defined in class path resource [processengine-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'processDefinitionFactory' while setting bean property 'processDefinitionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultProcessDefinitionFactory' defined in class path resource [processengine-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'iwaConsignmentOrderExceptionEmailAction' is defined
```

Errors listed above, How to solve it?

Comment: There is a bean missing : `iwaConsignmentOrderExceptionEmailAction` Check that it's defined and that the extension containing it is loaded (verify localextensions.xml + logs to be sure)

Comment: Thanks, I've solved it by myself. The best way is reverting DB data, because DB data is all messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Because essential data recreated, DB data may be all messed up. The best way is reverting your DB data if you have data backup.